# AsyncTask #3 error parsing JSON object. String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

Can someone please tell me what my error is? I downloaded this code from AndroidHive.info. I keeping getting a "Error parsing data error. Also can someone show me how to find out what line the error is on?

```
public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputPrice;
    EditText inputDesc;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/include/create_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

        // Edit Text
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
        inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

        // button click event
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

**here is my logcat**

```
01-26 18:14:35.366: D/dalvikvm(12395): GC_CONCURRENT freed 72K, 52% free 2619K/5379K, external 1529K/2026K, paused 8ms+2ms
01-26 18:14:36.296: E/JSON Parser(12395): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Unknown of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-26 18:14:36.296: W/dalvikvm(12395): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8560)
01-26 18:14:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(12395): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-26 18:14:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(12395): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-26 18:14:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(12395):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
01-26 18:14:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(12395):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
01-26 18:14:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(12395):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
01-26 18:14:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(12395):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
01-26 18:14:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(12395):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-26 18:14:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(12395):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-26 18:14:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(12395):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-26 18:14:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(12395):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-26 18:14:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(12395): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 18:14:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(12395):    at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:129)
01-26 18:14:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(12395):    at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
01-26 18:14:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(12395):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-26 18:14:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(12395):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
01-26 18:14:36.306: E/AndroidRuntime(12395):    ... 4 more
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395): Activity com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2afca938 that was originally added here
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2afca938 that was originally added here
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:265)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(AllProductsActivity.java:116)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity.onCreate(AllProductsActivity.java:57)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
01-26 18:14:36.566: E/WindowManager(12395):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-26 18:16:02.626: I/Process(12395): Sending signal. PID: 12395 SIG: 9
```

Thanks!

EDIT:Here is the code for AllProductsActivity.java:

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products =    "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/include/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received 
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
             Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString()); 

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS); 

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Line seams to be **AllProductsActivity.java:129**. Provide us with dump of JSON string to be parsed.

Comment: Post the code for AllProductsActivity. Also, which JSON parser are you using?

Comment: @ErikNedwidek I posted the code for AllProductsActivity.java...I'm not sure which JSON parser I am using...I'm fairly new to Android. Just trying to get these tutorials to work ;)

Comment: @jtrain - Oh, I'm an idiot. They're using the internal one. I've used that before and switched to GSON as fast as possible (seem to have also put a mental block the fact that the internal exists).

Comment: @ErikNedwidek Ok I see. Thanks for taking the time to check out my code!

Comment: @jtrain - I've updated my answer. Hopefully that gets you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

First, wrap your method in a

```
try{
} catch(Throwable t) { Log.e("MyActivity", t.getMessage(), t); }
```

You should get an easier to read stack trace.

To make this code work you need to have "include/get_all_products.php" on a web server. Then you need to update the URL defined in url_all_products with your server's IP address. Have you done this?

The internal JSON parser is usable for small amounts of data. For more data, something like GSON will save your sanity.